# Configure Okta SAML application via Terraform

Tags: terraform, okta

I would like to create a SAML application via Okta provider in terraform.
When we create a SAML application in Okta there is a **Feedback** step like the screenshot [image]

I was following this terraform example https://github.com/okta/terraform-provider-okta/blob/master/examples/okta_app_saml/updated.tf but I cannot find any parameters related to the feedback section.

Is there a way that we can configure this part via terraform?

Comment: What have you tried already? Is there any code? If so, are there any errors you are facing?

Comment: I've found this example https://github.com/okta/terraform-provider-okta/blob/master/examples/okta_app_saml/updated.tf but cannot found the feedback parameters

Comment: Why would you need feedback in terraform?

Comment: I was wondering if it's possible or not. I'm trying to do some prof of concept to automate creating the Okta application and feedback is part of the process

Comment: I don't believe it's a part of SAML application object in Okta API